# where should define create TRIGGER in mysql

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO users_roles
SET uid = NEW.uid;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: check that NEW.uid is having value or empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varchar(32) not null,
created_date datetime not null
)
engine=innodb;

delimiter #

create trigger users_before_ins_trig before insert on users
for each row
begin
  set new.created_date = now();
end#

delimiter ;

insert into users (username) values ('f00'),('bar');

mysql> select * from users;
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| user_id | username | created_date        |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
|       1 | f00      | 2011-03-14 12:39:38 |
|       2 | bar      | 2011-03-14 12:39:38 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT**

The trigger is all you need - edit as appropriate for your schema !!

```
delimiter #

create trigger users_before_ins_trig before insert on users
for each row
begin
  set new.created_date = now();
end#

delimiter ;
```

Comment: i dont use PHPMyAdmin but there must be a query option somewhere then all you'll need to do is copy and paste the trigger code (from delimiter # to delimiter ;), edit the trigger code to suit your tables and execute it. see EDIT

Comment: Thanks a lot.   `delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO beep  SET uid = NEW.uid;
  END;
|

delimiter ;`

Answer (score 0):

You have only a small syntax error, you need to remove the `BEGIN` before `INSERT`

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH 
ROW INSERT INTO users_roles
SET uid = NEW.uid;
```

Will work

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT syntax is wrong.

The syntax should follow one of

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?)
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET column = ? [WHERE column = ?)
```

Comment: please see manual mysql     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

where?? **Run SQL query/queries on database in phpmyadmin**

code:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO beep  SET uid = NEW.uid;
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```